# Canonical paths: why are they needed?

Tags: filenames, symlink, path

The issue of resolving symlinks (symbolic links) is often addressed on
this forum, and on others. Related are the concepts of relative,
absolute (or full), and canonical (or resolved) pathnames. Two now
standard utilities are available, for example in GNU core utilities,
to resolve symlinks, and, among other things, produce canonical
pathnames: [`readlink`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/readlink-invocation.html) and [`realpath`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/realpath-invocation.html).

Why do we need canonical paths?

Can you give examples where canonical paths are required, and non-canonical absolute paths will not be acceptable?

Side question: why do people get "canonical path" answers for "absolute path"
questions? But is this technology or sociology ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need canonical paths to determine the volume a file system object resides on (if you want to do it that way; there are other ways).
2. If access rights refer to paths (like with Apache) then you need canonical paths.

Comment: Can you expand on #1?

Comment: @dubiousjim `/data/README.txt` can be on a volume which is mounted on /home. You need to know whether it happens to be a link to e.g. `/home/user/README.txt`.

Comment: Thanks, I meant could you expand on the parentheses :-).

Comment: @dubiousjim You can ask the kernel directly: `man 2 lstat` (dev_t)

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using `df` for that purpose.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using `df` for that purpose ? Well, I
realize I should have made my original question more precise. I was
thinking mainly of a shell user. Canonical paths seem possibly more likely to be
useful when programming in C. But both contexts sare interesting. My
initial question was motivated by my puzzlement over the design of
`readlink` as a shell command, compared to `realpath`. But then the
explanation is probably that designing the shell utilities should be different from designing a library.

Comment: @babou I don't see any problem abusing `df` for that.