# What is the value, proper use, and behavior of a command's "absolute path"?

Tags: filenames

We have many questions that address an *absolute path*, sometimes for files, sometimes for commands. I want a central knowledge base question about what exactly an *absolute path* ***does*** as it relates to commands (not only files).

## What does an *absolute path* for commands achieve and how does it affect work in Unix & Linux?

- How does an *absolute path* behave differently from a *relative path*?
- Does the *absolute path* override the environment `$PATH` setting?
- Does anything additional happen in command substitution: `$(/bin/echo Hello world)`
- Is an *absolute path* better in scripting?
- Why are there sometimes many *absolute paths* for a command?

  - `/usr/bin/echo`
  - `/bin/echo`
  - Both work on the same system
  - Is one more consistent across distros or preferred by POSIX?
- Why do some commands, like `cd` not have any *absolute path*?
- Why would or would not *or should* we use an *absolute path* in scripting?

  - *Absolute paths* are [relevant in scripting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/726744/315069)
- Do shell interpreters care about *absolute paths*, such as `bash` vs `zsh`?

---

Disambiguation

- This asks about any given command's:

  - *Absolute path* (`/usr/bin/echo`)
  - In contrast to its *relative path* (`echo`)
- I'm not asking about [canonical paths](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77451/) as they relate to symlinks.
- I am not asking about [absolute vs relative vs canonical](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398415/315069) paths or their basic definition (ie: *POSIX filename with `/` slash indicating directory tree*, etc)

Comment: 40 years ago, I had been instructed to always refer to commands by their absolute path when logged as root. I have kept this habit. I remember having commented that way some QA here… which triggered some… amusement from other knowledgeable contributors. So… apart from some obvious-to-me security reasons, particularily when sysadmin of OS-devs dedicated systems is shared… let's acknowledge that using absolute path for commands is a matter of… personal idiom ;-)

Comment: Hi, I believe that the answer you link to about the difference between relative and absolute paths actually fully defines what an absolute path is! Could you elaborate on what questions specifically remain open?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think my question is more about its *use* and *behavior*, not so much the definition of its static existence. I'll make an edit to that effect. Thanks!

Comment: @MC68020 With examples, that could be an actual answer. I remember four years ago when I went back through all my shell code and changed it to relative paths, even inside command substitution, for that security reason specifically.

Comment: Your statement that `echo` is executed by its relative path is not correct. You'd have to use something like `../echo` for this to apply. `echo` is also a bad example since it is also a shell built-in. Using `/usr/bin/bash` uses the absolute path, using `bash` searches the $PATH variable, which may or may not include relative paths.

Comment: @doneal24 I want to clean up this question, but what is the *correct* term, then? If `/usr/bin/cat` is *absolute path*, what is just `cat`? I originally categorized it as a kind of relative because it is *relative to `$PATH`*. So, I'm wrong, but what is it then? *Normal*? *Command*?

Comment: I'm beginning to think that I have about five questions here that need to be asked as five questions rather than four in the post plus one in the comments. @doneal24 plz help.

Comment: @Jesse I don't think that an unqualified command actually falls into this discussion. The command `cat` can be executed as `/usr/bin/cat`, `$HOME/bin/cat`, or as `./cat` depending on how `$PATH` is defined. The distinction may fall into how a shell interprets a command, possibly using $PATH in its interpretation. It is even more murky when you look at `echo` which is usually a shell built-in but can also be called as `/usr/bin/echo`. Even worse is the semantics of the built-in and the shell are different.

Comment: @doneal24 not trying to troll, but I'm working with an education curriculum and I need to be able to talk about this with students. So, it would be okay to say, "The *absolute path* to the command `/usr/bin/cat` should run the *plain command* `cat`." I think I could say *plain command* in a similar situation without causing a problem, from what you say. Thank you, while it seems unimportant to most.

Comment: [mods: please don't delete these comments, I need to come back and clean this up when I get time and want the comments for reference]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - How does an absolute path behave differently from a relative path?
> - Does the absolute path override the environment $PATH setting?
> - Does anything additional happen in command substitution: $(/bin/echo Hello world)

Both absolute and relative paths override `$PATH`. What matters is whether a `/` is present. If it is `/some/command` or `./some/command` or `some/command`, the command at that location, whether absolute or relative, will be executed, instead of being looked up in `$PATH`. If it is `some-command` without a slash, it will be looked up in `$PATH`. Command substitution doesn't affect this.

> - Why are there sometimes many absolute paths for a command?

This depends on the system. On [Linux systems with UsrMerge](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/) (even though the page mentions Fedora, this inlcudes recent Ubuntu, Debian, Arch Linux, etc.), `/bin` is a symlink to `/usr/bin`, so `/bin/echo` and `/usr/bin/echo` are the same. On Solaris, more standards-compliant utilities are provided in the XPG sections: [When to use XPG* version of a command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/198905/) Other systems might have other reasons.

> - Why do some commands, like `cd` not have any absolute path?

Sometimes they do: [What is the point of the `cd` external command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50058/70524), sometimes they don't: [Why is cd not a program?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38808/70524)

---

As for all the "should"s and "shouldn't"s, it depends on what you want to do. Sometimes I have seen people use absolute paths because they think it will keep them safe from any alternate version of tools that a user might have installed. Sometimes I have seen this cause trouble to people trying to port software to another system where the tools at those absolute paths aren't the expected ones, but the alternate versions installed by the user would have worked.